# How to get index of an item in Listbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a function that needs to search an for item whose ID is entered in an entry field, and select that item in a listbox.

So far I managed to get it to return the correct item, but I don't know how to select that item, or if it's even possible to.

```
 self.__searchVar=StringVar()
        self.__entrySearch=Entry(Panel,textvariable=self.__searchVar)
        self.__entrySearch.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

 Button(Panel, text="Search", width=10, 
             command=self.search).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=E)
```

```
    def search(self):
        for lbo in self.__patients:
            patient=self.__patients[lbo]
            if self.__entrySearch.get()==pacijent.lbo:
                print(pacijent)
                                              #get index
                                              #select item with that index in 
                                               the listbox
```

I wanted to get the index from that item and then select it, but I don't really know how. If someone could help, that would be great.

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.curselection-method

Comment: @ipaleka but the item isnot selected, i just get the lbo (like id) and i need to select the right item with that id

Comment: There are a lot of other methods on that page, to select use [selection_set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_set-method).

Comment: @ipaleka I tried most of that, selection_set requiers an index of that item which i dont have

Comment: If you did it right then you have a list of possible items and you'll get the index from your entry value with `index = data.index(self.__entrySearch.get())`.